# How to assign PL/SQL as part of a variable and execute the variable as a Query string in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the below query:

```
DECLARE vquery Varchar2(5000) := 'CREATE TABLE  MYSCHEMA.MyTable ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL, Badge INTEGER NOT NULL,Password NVARCHAR2(50),PRIMARY KEY (ID))' ;

Begin
--EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vquery;--This is what I want to execute
dbms_output.put_line('VQUERY is: '' || vquery || ');--Just wanted to test
End;
```

Now the Problems are:

1. It is saying PL/SQL successfully completed,but I want to see the vquery in put_line as output,it is not coming.
2. All I want is to create that table by finally running:

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vquery;

   I am using PL/SQL Developer.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the quotes are not right - try `dbms_output.put_line('VQUERY is: ' || vquery);`

Comment: I am able to successfully execute,but the vquery output is not printing..using pl/sql developer..any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a minor syntax error, vquery was a string as you included the variable as part of the string

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('VQUERY is: ' || vquery);
```

instead of

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('VQUERY is: '' || vquery || ');
```

so try as

```
DECLARE
   vquery   VARCHAR2 (5000);
BEGIN
   vquery :=
      'CREATE TABLE  MyTable ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL, Badge INTEGER NOT NULL,Password NVARCHAR2(50),PRIMARY KEY (ID))';

   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vquery;--This is what I want to execute
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('VQUERY is: ' || vquery);       --Just wanted to test
END;
```

Comment: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.---I am getting this, but the output is not printing..

Comment: @user2948533 In PL/SQL Developer, there will be a setting to see the output or try adding `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`  before the  `DECLARE`

Comment: Perfect!I tried set serveroutput on size 30000;..it resolved..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DEFINE instead of DECLARE:

```
DEFINE vquery = 'CREATE TABLE  MYSCHEMA.MyTable ( ID INTEGER NOT NULL, - 
    Badge INTEGER NOT NULL, Password NVARCHAR2(50),PRIMARY KEY (ID))'

&vquery;
```

I'm not 100% positive on this one, but I am adapting it from this: [Define a VIEW in Oracle without using CREATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686070/define-a-view-in-oracle-without-using-create). There are a couple of good solutions that both worked for me there.

Comment: Thanks for your help SandPiper,seems I was missing a setting:set serveroutput on size 30000;..